# Ubuntu 20.04 unexpectedly shuts down

Tags: shutdown, gnome-shell

I was running Nutch Crawler on my Ubuntu machine and I found my PC shut down. My machine's power is on and I tried to ping it, but there was no response. I don't know what is the reason for that.

I've checked my `syslog` and found the last log on the last boot.

```
gnome-shell[1226]: g_dbus_connection_emit_signal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
```

What causes my PC to shut down unexpectedly?

Comment: dunno what's going on ur PC...
So let me ask question.
1. Does it always happen when u run "Nutch Crawler"? And i don't know what it is, so can u tell me what "Nutch Crawler" is?

2. Is your PC shut down even if you doesn't start "Nutch Crawler"?

Comment: @heechanLee Nutch 

1-1. it had been running about 5 days, but unexpectedly shut down

1-2. Nutch is a Web crawler that collect web page data. it crawls web page with map/reduce and stores data on HDFS

2. No